# useEffect not updating variables on function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called Date with **three variables**. I also have a function called **setCurrentTimes** that is supposed to update the variables each time it is called with the current values.

I **call the function inside react's useEffect** that has no dependencies to update the variables on the component mount.

Here is the date component.

```
const Date = () => {
  var currentDate;
  var currentTime;
  var amOrPm;

  const setCurrentTimes = () => {
    currentDate = moment().format("d MMMM YYYY");
    currentTime = moment().format(" h:mm:ss ");
    amOrPm = moment().format("a");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentTimes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Date flex__container-v">
      {amOrPm === "pm" ? (
        <div className="Moon__icon flex__container">
          <img src={Assets.Moon} alt="Moon Icon" />
          <p className="p__poppins Date__greeting">Good Evening</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="Sun__icon flex__container">
          <img src={Assets.Sun} alt="Sun Icon" />
          <p className="p__poppins Date__greeting">Good Morning</p>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="Date__btm flex__container">
        <p className="p__poppins">{currentDate}</p>
        <p className="p__poppins">{currentTime}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The **component returns different things depending on the variables**. However, it is not working as expected. When I try to log out the variables inside the return statement I get **undefined.**

I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I dont understand why you cannot simply use state as it was meant to do exactly this.

Comment: You need to operate in useEffect on states.

Comment: Try to use useState()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use state in order to fix this.

Longer answer:

You are probably expecting useEffect to run before render, but this is not the case.

> useEffect is always called after the render phase of the component.
> Your ParentComponent consists of Input, Input & ChildComponent.

In your case you are trying to display variables that are not yet set. If you were to use State instead of variables your UI would re-render after setting these states. Since you're using variables your UI wont re-render causing it to always display the initial values (which is empty).

simplified example:

```
const Date = () => {

    const [currentDate,setCurrentDate] = React.useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      setCurrentDate(moment().format("d MMMM YYYY"));
    }, []);
  
    return (
      <div className="Date flex__container-v">
        <div className="Date__btm flex__container">
          <p className="p__poppins">{currentDate}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Can you show me a code example though? If you don't mind.

Comment: @AmohPrince i added a simplified example, obviously you would have to fill in the rest yourself, but this is the idea with state